# how to do line fitting multiple lines MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying find all straight lines in an image which is border. for example,stamps have four edges and I have already find those edges by `edge` function in MATLAB. But there is a problem that they are not real straight line. so I need to use line fitting to get all four borders. But `polyfit` function can only fit one line at one time. Is there any solutions that can fit all lines at one time.
for example：[here](http://s1294.photobucket.com/user/ssjssh/library/?sort=3&page=1) I upload some pictures,the image with red lines is what I want. Please be ware I need four separate lines.

Comment: There is nothing to see at the link you post. Only mentions a private archive. Furthermore, do you just have pictures or also underlying data? And if you can fit 1 line with `polyfit`, then why not simply use `polyfit` 4 times?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin sorry, I am new to that website, can you see now?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin but the four lines are twisted by each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the image you won't be trying to smooth some lines, or fill in the gaps. Instead it looks more like you need to put your image in the smallest possible box.

Here is an algorithm that you can try:

1. Start from all 4 corners.
2. 'walk' one of the corners inwards and determine if all points are still within four corners
3. If so, save this corner and go to step 2, else go to step 2

Keep repeating step 2 and 3 till you have a steady solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get rid of the perforations?  In that case I would suggest using thresholding to segment out dark areas of the image, and then using `regionprops` to get their bounding boxes. Then you can figure out the largest rectangle that excludes them.